# Efficiently match highest category

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 6 digit numbers that can range from 0-9 and I would match that against a number in 6 categories

- first number match
- first two number match
- first three number match
- first four number match
- first five number match
- all numbers match

But only the highest category per matching number should be selected. An example

Number: 123456

- If one has the number [123]756 then this would fall into category first three number match
- On number 023456 then this would be no match

I created a fiddle for it https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/TZCrFPnJpkw4fyxA5Q6mR/1

Here an example:

Numbers:

| number |
| --- |
| 123456 |
| 123000 |
| 023456 |
| 123477 |
| 133456 |

Number to match against: 123456 should return

| common_digits | number |
| --- | --- |
| 6 | 123456 |
| 3 | 123000 |
| 0 | 023456 |
| 4 | 123477 |
| 1 | 133456 |

What would be an efficient method? The brute force solution would be a double loop I suppose starting with 6 matches, 5 matches, ...

Comment: What version are you on? 5.3 as indicated in the fiddle or higher?  if so what?  I would think a recursive CTE is what you're after.   but it's started availability is 8.0

Comment: have not yet decided on version so quite open

Answer (score 2):

```sql
SELECT @number tested_number, 7 - LENGTH(nums.num) common_digits, bids.*
FROM bids
JOIN (SELECT 1 num UNION 
      SELECT 10 UNION 
      SELECT 100 UNION 
      SELECT 1000 UNION 
      SELECT 10000 UNION 
      SELECT 100000) nums
WHERE @number DIV nums.num = bids.ticketNumber DIV nums.num
ORDER BY nums.num LIMIT 1;
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/TZCrFPnJpkw4fyxA5Q6mR/4

Comment: Does not seem to work. ticket number 150874 comes up twice in bucket 1 and 2 on the number 153456

Comment: @Chris Do you want to say that you receive two output rows with `LIMIT 1` ?

Comment: this is not correct. It only returns 1 result. Non any matching result.

Comment: it should not return 1 result but any number that match in those 6 categories. Just the single number can only be in the highest category and not in any other

Comment: @Chris *It only returns 1 result. Non any matching result.* ??? From your question: *But **only the highest category** should be selected.* In my opinion, this is an unambiguous requirement to return strictly one output row.

Comment: then this is a misunderstanding. Only the highest category per matching number should be returned. The number 150874 and the matching number 151111 the first 2 digits match and it should be category two. I have edited the question

Comment: @Chris Use LEFT JOIN, convert WHERE clause to ON clause, remove LIMIT. You'll obtain a query which returns all matches, even partial, for each pattern. Use this as subquery and select the rows with the highest length per each pattern number.

Comment: Hm but partial patterns are not allowed. The must match starting from the first digit. In between matches are not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
select *
from (
  select 6 as score, b.* from bids b where ticketNumber like '123456%'
  union all select 5, b.* from bids b where ticketNumber like '12345%'
  union all select 4, b.* from bids b where ticketNumber like '1234%'
  union all select 3, b.* from bids b where ticketNumber like '123%'
  union all select 2, b.* from bids b where ticketNumber like '12%'
  union all select 1, b.* from bids b where ticketNumber like '1%'
) x
order by score desc
limit 1
```

Result:

```
 score  id  roundId  address  ticketNumber 
 ------ --- -------- -------- ------------ 
 6      1   1        12345    123456
```

See example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/TZCrFPnJpkw4fyxA5Q6mR/2).

Alternatively you can use a recursive CTE, but that's not available in MySQL 5.7 (as your fiddle implies).

Comment: how would a recursive CTE version look like?